# Break loop with variable - Python

Tags: python, loops, tuples, break

I'd like to write my loop in a more compact form. When I have code in this form, everything works fine:

```
a=-1
while a <0:
    user_move()
    if (nastede[1]==X) and (nastede[2]==X) and (nastede[3]==X):
        print("Game Over")
        break

print("END")
```

But when I try to use the code in this form, my loop does not break:

```
y=(nastede[1] and nastede[2] and nastede[3])

a=-1
while a <0:
    user_move()
    if y == X:
        print("Game Over")
        break

print("END")
```

Why does my loop in the second situation not break with `nastede[]` inside `y` ?

**After changes (All Code):**

```
nastede=[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
X="X"

def list_global():
    global nastede
    print(" ",nastede[0],"| ",nastede[1]," | ",nastede[2]," ")
    print("---------------")
    print(" ",nastede[3],"| ",nastede[4]," | ",nastede[5]," ")
    print("---------------")
    print(" ",nastede[6],"| ",nastede[7]," | ",nastede[8]," ")

def user_move():
    a=-1
    while a<0:
        move_hum=int(input("Write a number from 1 to 8 ?\n"))
        if (nastede[move_hum] != X) and (nastede[move_hum] != O):
            nastede[move_hum] = "X"
            list_global()
            break
        else:
            print("Write different number")


a=-1
while a <0:
    user_move()
    if all(map(lambda x: x == X, nastede)):
        print("Game Over")
        break

print("END")
```

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: in the second example `y` only contains a boolean

Comment: why are you redefining `all`? you can use it straight away by default.

Comment: Yes, now i see. I removed redefining 'all' from my code. But still loop does not break, maybe you see a little more wrong things in my code?

Comment: I added the whole code. I will be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition `y=(nastede[1] and nastede[2] and nastede[3])` will bind `y` to `True`, and unless `X` is `True` also that will not be evaluated as you are expecting.

Better use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) combined with `map`:

```
...
if all(map(lambda x: x == X, nestede))
...
```

Here you have a [minimal example](https://repl.it/repls/SomeLinenProgrammingtool)

**EDIT**:
Since `all` checks all this code would fail, because you only check from the index `1` to `3`, for that use a `slice`:

```
...
if all(map(lambda x: x == X, nestede[1:4]))
...
```

remember that python slices are not tail inclusive `[x,y)`

Comment: `def all(iterable):
        for element in iterable:
            if not element:
                return False
        return True
    a=-1
    while a <0:
        user_move()
        if if all(map(lambda x: x == X, nastede)):
                print("Game Over")
            break`

When i tried use the code in this form ^, Python still don't break a loop. Maybe i must change something in lambda? but i read these https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php and all look good.

Comment: @MaddieGraham, can you update your question with that code please? im seeing some serius problems there but i cannot confirm without propper identation.

Comment: @MaddieGraham, the edit should explain why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

`(nastede[1]==X) and (nastede[2]==X) and (nastede[3]==X)`  and `(nastede[1] and nastede[2] and nastede[3])` are not same. In the first statement every value needs to be equal to `X` to get the truthy value. But in  the second code if all the values are truthy even they are not equal to `X` then the expression will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Also better:

```
....
if all(i == X for i in nestede):
...
...
```